# Fetching data with react and mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data from an API call with react and map it so that I can iterate through a list of items. Issue is there is nothing being returned in the list when fetching with react although there is data when I make the API call, could the issue be related to the mapping or with the state? I have included as much code so you can see from the presentation layer to repository including example data that gets returned in the API. I am new to react.

React code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './PracticeAreas.css';

import IReportGroup from 'src/model/IReportGroup';

interface IOwnProps {
    callAction: any
}

interface IOwnState {
    groups: IReportGroup[]
}

class PracticeAreas extends React.Component<IOwnProps, IOwnState> {

    constructor(props: IOwnProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          groups: []
        }
      }

    public render() {

        return (
        <div className="col-md-12 practiceAreas">
            <h1>Practice Areas</h1>
            <div className="item-container plain-bg selection-refinement">
                <div className="refinement-search">
                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul className="list-inline groupedTags">
                {this.state.groups}
            </ul>
        </div>
        );
    }

    public groups() {
        fetch(`https://localhost:44301/api/v2/navigator/reports/groups`)
            .then((res) => res.json()
            .then((data) => { 
                const groups = data.results.map((group: IReportGroup) => {
                    return( <li key={group.id}>{group.name}</li>
                )
        })
        this.setState({groups: groups});
        }))
    }
};

export default PracticeAreas
```

API call

```
[Route("groups")]
[HttpGet]
public IList<NavigatorReportSelectionGroup> GetGroups()
{
    var groups = navigatorReportSelectionService.GetGroups();
    return groups.ToList();
}
```

Service call

```
public IList<NavigatorReportSelectionGroup> GetGroups()
{
    var allTopicGroups = navigatorService.GetTopicGroups();

    return
        allTopicGroups.Select(x => new NavigatorReportSelectionGroup
        {
            Id = x.GroupId,
            Name = x.Name
        }).ToList();
}
```

Repo

```
public IEnumerable<NavigatorTopicGroup> GetTopicGroups()
{
    return navigatorTopicGroupRepository.GetAll();
}
```

Model

```
public class NavigatorTopicGroup
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Example API data

```
<NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
    <Focused>false</Focused>
    <Id>a184e2c5-af49-413e-9747-06741e97a512</Id>
    <Name>Insurance & Reinsurance group</Name>
    <Order>0</Order>
    <Type>Topics</Type>
</NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
<NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
    <Focused>false</Focused>
    <Id>955e3e12-6e02-4e77-bcec-08b2fcb6f3e8</Id>
    <Name>Patents group</Name>
    <Order>0</Order>
    <Type>Topics</Type>
</NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
<NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
    <Focused>false</Focused>
    <Id>d21384b5-27be-4bfc-963d-0d2ad40dbbfb</Id>
    <Name>Employment: Canada group</Name>
    <Order>0</Order>
    <Type>Topics</Type>
</NavigatorReportSelectionGroup>
```

IReportGroup:

```
export default interface IReportGroup {
    id: string,
    type: ReportOptionType,
    name: string,
    order: number,
    focused: boolean
}
```

Comment: why `c#` as tag?

Comment: I do not see the function `groups` called anywhere. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Kabbany took the words out of my mouth. I didn't see it being invoked either...idk

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a scope issue. You should put the call to `this.setState` after the result mapping.

Second, you have the closing parentheses for the first `then` block in the wrong place.

Thirdly, javascript doesn't require you set functions as `public` or `private`.

Try this:

```
groups() {
    fetch(`https://localhost:44301/api/v2/navigator/reports/groups`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => { 
            const groups = data.results.map((group: IReportGroup) => {
                return( <li key={group.id}>{group.name}</li>)
            })
            this.setState({groups: groups});
        })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a return statement in your `fetch`. This is a common mistake and easy to fix.

Take this:

```
public groups() {
        fetch(`https://***`)
            .then((res) => res.json()
            .then((data) => { 
                const groups = data.results.map((group: IReportGroup) => {
                    return( <li key={group.id}>{group.name}</li>
                )
        })
         this.setState({groups: groups});
        }))
    }
```

and adjust it to look like this: (all I am changing is adding the missing return statement)

```
groups() {
        fetch(`https://***`)
            .then(res => { return res.json(); })
            .then(data => { 
                const groups = data.results.map((group: IReportGroup) => {
                    return( <li key={group.id}>{group.name}</li>
                )
                this.setState({groups});
        })
        }))
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

There are a few areas in your source that can be adjusted. I'm guessing you have an OOP background. You don't need to declare your functions as `public` or `private`.

Your `setState` is out of scope. So it's not setting anything. I'm not exactly sure what outcome you are going for...but I would just assign `const group` to `data.results` then set your state immediately after that like so:

```
const groups = data.results; 
this.setState({ groups });
```

Then you want to map that array where ever you want those results rendered. I'm not sure you are invoking this function anywhere either. Your source is a little hard to read maybe I overlooked it.

I'll end there.

Comment: there is no missing return. Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow functions automatically return whatever comes after as long as it isn't a function

Comment: I have never seen React source done the way you have it so I'm assuming you are a super pro and what you are doing is above my pay grade :)

Comment: okay...console.log(data) in the second then statement...do you see data?

Comment: Well, not as is, because the closing parenthesis on the first `then` block is after the second one but it should be before.

Comment: Not according to the [syntax documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax) it should work fine then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185365/discussion-between-bens-steves-and-smarticles101).

Comment: reposting in case this answer helps someone else who comes across this